# Create an Array of Strings with the YouTube API Tags

Tags: swift, youtube-api, alamofire

I have an app where I am using the YouTube API and Alamofire. Using the YouTube API, I get a response with an array of tags for the video. Like this:

```
tags =         (
            tag1,
            "tag2",
            "tag3",
            "tag4",
            "tag5"
        );
```

Normally, you get a response like

```
title = "NEW Google Home Products!!";
```

and then you can set a string to

```
var videoTitle:String = ""
```

and then in the response from Alamofire...

```
videoTitle = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "statistics.commentCount") as! String
```

But, because the tags return an array of strings as you can see above, this method will not work. How would I create a variable for an array of strings that I can set to the array of tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about casting it to an array of `String`s?

```
if let tags = (items as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: "tags") as? [String] {
    print(tags) //[tag1, tag2] ...
}
```